# Looking for an Angular 7 version of Vue.js "nextTick"

Tags: angular, vue.js

I'm developing a page in Angular 7, where i want to do something (scroll to section) after i'm sure the page has re rendered. The section i want to scroll to is initially hidden with an ngif and when the section is shown and completely rendered in the DOM, then i want to scroll to it. I've used Vue.js before and their callback function nextTick, which has been working but i can't find a similar solution in angular. I'd rather not use a setTimeout because if set to 0 the DOM is not always ready and re rendered and setting it higher makes it delayed.

Comment: You could use [Angular animations callbacks](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put inside your *ngIf a component and use the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook which will call a parent function after he rendered properly.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: Yes that would work. But I would like to have it in the same component. Because it altso contains reactive form elements

Comment: @Nicki why would it not be in the same component? I think `ngAfterViewInit` is the way to go here

Comment: Just to understad this correctly. Do you mean to use an empty component just to get the callback when it has rendered, or du you mean that i should put the code that goes in the ng-if inside this component? Because this has a part of a reactive form, and then i'd have to make a custum value accessor?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try `requestAnimationFrame`? It worked for me. You don't need to set a time while DOM is always rerendered and runs with no delay.

Comment: Mind posting a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

well the angular alternate would be setting settimeout to 0 in your code where the if flag is changed and then immediately calling ChangeDetectorRef.detectchanges() after it so it shall force to detect the change in the immediate next cycle, something in your component like

```
...
sectionRendered = false;
constructor(private cdf: ChangeDetectorRef){
}
function renderSection(){
 this.sectionRendered = true;
 setTimeout(() => {
   // here you can access the relevant component
   this.scrollSection();
 }, 0);
 this.cdf.detectChanges();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Version 16 Angular introduced new application-level lifecycle hooks focused on running code after Angular performs any rendering operations, namely `afterRender` and `afterNextRender` (see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#reading-and-writing-the-dom)).

Note that in contrast to Vue's 'nextTick' these functions can't simply be called wherever you need them, but must be used in an injection context, such as the constructor for your component class:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponentClass {
  constructor() {
    afterRender(() => {
      // called whenever the DOM is updated
    })
  }
}
```